# Is it possible to reuse pre-built Text in CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a few parameters passed to one of my CloudFormation conf file like this (YAML):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AWS CloudFormation Template for creating pipeline workflow.
Parameters:

  Opt1:
    Description: my opt1
    Type: String
    Default: opt1_default

  Opt2:
    Description: my opt2
    Type: String
    Default: opt2_default

  Opt3:
    Description: my opt3
    Type: String
    Default: opt3_default
  ...
```

In many other parts of my conf I keep on use:

```
...
Name: !Sub '${Opt1}-${Opt2}-${Opt3}'
...
Name: !Sub '${Opt1}-${Opt2}-${Opt3}'
...
Name: !Sub '${Opt1}-${Opt2}-${Opt3}'
...
```

Is it possible to create some reference like:

```
SomeRef: !Sub '${Opt1}-${Opt2}-${Opt3}'
```

in a way that I can do:

```
...
Name: !Ref SomeRef
...
Name: !Ref SomeRef
...
Name: !Ref SomeRef
...
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested template with no resources and single output can do it:

**NameCreator.yaml**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: 'Empty nested template'

Parameters:
  Opt1:
    Type: String
  Opt2:
    Type: String

Conditions:
  Never: !Equals [ a, b ]
Resources:
  NullResource:
    Type: Custom::Null
    Condition: Never

Outputs:
  Name:
    Value: !Sub '${Opt1}-${Opt2}'
```

And then in main template call it:

```
  NameCreator:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        Opt1: !Ref Opt1
        Opt2: !Ref Opt2
      TemplateURL: https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/NameCreator.yaml
```

and use it:

```
  Name: !GetAtt 'NameCreator.Outputs.Name'
```